# subprocess.Popen is not running shell command

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I am trying to use `subprocess.Popen` to run **'cat test.txt | grep txt'**, but it's not working. In my code I have executed the `subprocess.Popen` command twice.

> 1: First time I used it to run a tshark command which redirectes the command output to a text (test.txt) file (which works fine). (**defined in function get_all_tshark_out in below code**)
>
> 2: Second time used subprocess.Popen to run 'cat test.txt | grep txt' command to extract txt from this file to perform some validation. This didn't work for me. (**defined in function get_uniq_sessions in below code**)

To make sure it's not because of buffer overflow I am flushing `stdout` also, but didn't get any help. Below is my code:

```
import subprocess
import logging

def get_all_tshark_out(logger, tcpdump, port):
    command = """tshark -r "%s" -odiameter.tcp.ports:"%s" -R 'diameter.cmd.code == 272 and diameter.flags.request==0 and !tcp.analysis.retransmission and diameter.flags.T == 0' -Tpdml -Tfields -ediameter.Session-Id | sort > test.txt""" %(tcpdump, port)
    p_out = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stderr.flush()
    return 1

def get_uniq_sessions(logger, id='1234', uniqlog_file='test.txt'):
    command = "cat "+ uniqlog_file +" | grep "+ id
    print command
    p_out = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    print "PPPPP", p_out
    output = p_out.stdout.read()
    p_out.wait()
    command_out_list = (output.strip().split("\n"))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print "%%%", output, p_out.stderr.read()
    print len(command_out_list)
    if p_out.stderr.read():
        logger.error("\"%s\" Error happened while trying to execute \"%s\"" (p_out.stderr.read().strip(), command))
        sys.exit(1)
    elif command_out_list[0] == '' and len(command_out_list) == 1:
        logger.error("No Sessions belongs to %s campaign ID please provide proper input as Campaign ID" %id)
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        return command_out_list
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: *But its not working*, or *This didn't work for me* mean nothing. Please say as precisely as possible what actually happens: program hangs, after what output, exception, or ... ?

Comment: You could do all this with re so not sure why you are using a complicated subprocess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** *Both* of your `subprocess.Popen()` calls are broken; use one of the wrapper methods in `subprocess` instead, and/or use Python's built-in facilities instead of external tools.

Is there a particular reason you use a [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)?  Just `subprocess.Popen(['grep', id, uniqlog_file])` would be much simpler, and not require `shell=True` -- but of course, Python by itself is excellent at reading files and checking whether each line contains a string.

```
def get_uniq_sessions(logger, id='1234', uniqlog_file='test.txt'):
    matches = []
    with open(uniqlog_file, 'r') as handle:
        for line in handle:
            if id in line:
                matches.append(line)
    return matches
```

Your functions should probably not call `sys.exit()`; instead, raise an exception, or just return `None` -- that way, the calling code can decide how to handle errors and exceptions.

Your remaining `subprocess.Popen()` only coincidentally works as long as there is a limited amount of output.  You should probably use `subprocess.call` instead, which exists precisely for the purpose of running a subprocess under controlled conditions while checking for errors.

The key observation here is that `Popen()` itself merely spawns the subprocess.  You need to interact with it and `wait()` for it in order to make sure it succeeds and returns all its output.  The `call` and various `check_*` methods in the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) do this for you; `Popen()` is useful mainly when you outgrow the facilities of those canned wrappers, but also somewhat more tricky to get right, especially the first time.

The `tshark` command would not require a `shell=True` if you picked it apart into a list yourself, and did the sorting and writing to a file in Python.  If the sole purpose of the output file is to open it again from Python, I would recommend reading the raw output into a Python string and doing all the remaining processing in Python.

```
def get_all_tshark_out(logger, tcpdump, port):
    output = subprocess.check_output(['tshark', '-r', str(tcpdump),
        '-odiameter.tcp.ports:{0}'.format(port), '-R',
        'diameter.cmd.code == 272 and diameter.flags.request==0 '
            'and !tcp.analysis.retransmission and diameter.flags.T == 0',
        '-Tpdml', '-Tfields', '-ediameter.Session-Id'])
    return sorted(output)
```

... and now your `get_uniq_sessions` function is basically a one-liner:

```
 session = [x for x in get_all_tshark_out() if '1234' in x]
```